# How to animate td column visibility with CSS3

Tags: html, css

We have to hide a `td` column after n seconds (*immediately*) via CSS, when a class is applied to it; for example the column 2 in following snippet:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>column 1</td>
    <td>column 2</td>
    <td>column 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

We have already tried to play with `'visibility'` and `'opacity'` it works with `div` , but with `td` since the with visibility it maintain a width it doesn't work

In the following snippet the display is applied immediately instead of after to n seconds.

```js
function HideColumn() {
  var el = document.getElementById('columntarget');
  el.className += 'hideColumn';


}
```

```css
.hideColumn {
  display: none;
  transition: display 2s step-end;
}
td {
  width: 50px;
  
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style='background-color:red;'>column 1</td>
    <td style='background-color:yellow;' id="columntarget">column 2</td>
    <td style='background-color:blue;'>column 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick='HideColumn()'>Hide
  </button>
```

Any suggestion?

EDIT:

The @Harry snippet works fine, but what happen if we set the table width?

```js
function HideColumn() {
  var el = document.getElementById('columntarget');
  el.className += 'hideColumn';
}
```

```css
.hideColumn {
  width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 2s step-end;
}
div {
  width: 50px;
}
td {
  padding: 0px;
  
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table style='width:500px;' border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style='background-color:red;'>column 1</div>
    </td>
    <td style='width:auto'>
      <div style='background-color:blue;'>column 3</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div style='background-color:yellow;' id="columntarget">column 2</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick='HideColumn()'>Hide
</button>
```

Comment: After `n` seconds should it hide immediately or transition slowly?

Comment: Instead of adding class to the `td`, put a `div` inside the `td` and then add the class to it.

Comment: could you add an answer with a runnable snippet? :)

Comment: @Wintermute [here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/gja79roy/1).

Comment: @Vucko: Similar thoughts. I just posted an answer with something similar (with some extra modifications to fix the space in between).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `display` property of an element is not a transitionable or animatable property and so any change to that property's value will happen immediately regardless of any duration or delay that is set to it via the `transition` property.

You can do it like in the below snippet by setting the class to a `div` child of the `td`.

**Notes:**

- If you don't set `border-collapse: collapse` (that is, the borders are separate) then the border in between the `td` will look like it has doubled because even though the 2nd `td` has become `0px` wide, the `td` is still there and so the border will still be present.
- The `td` elements by default get a `1px` padding on all four sides (atleast in Chrome) and this also produces a space which can be nullified by using `padding: 0px` on the `td`.

```js
function HideColumn() {
  var el = document.getElementById('columntarget');
  el.className += 'hideColumn';
}
```

```css
.hideColumn {
  width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 2s step-end;
}
div {
  width: 50px;
}
td {
  padding: 0px;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style='background-color:red;'>column 1</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div style='background-color:yellow;' id="columntarget">column 2</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div style='background-color:blue;'>column 3</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick='HideColumn()'>Hide
</button>
```

---

I didn't fully understand what is the problem when `table` has been assigned a `width` because the `td` still hides after a delay. If you are referring to the two remaining columns expanding to occupy the full width then that can be addressed by doing the following:

- Set `table-layout: fixed;` to the table.
- Add a `width` (equal to the `div` width) to the `td` also.
- Apply the `.hideColumn` class to `td` via JS and transition the width of both the `td` and the `div`.

```js
function HideColumn() {
  var el = document.getElementById('columntarget');
  el.className += 'hideColumn';
}
```

```css
.hideColumn > div {
  width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 2s step-end;
}
td, div {
  width: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.hideColumn {
  width: 0px;
  transition: all 2s step-end;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:500px;" border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style='background-color:red;'>column 1</div>
    </td>
    <td style='width:auto'>
      <div style='background-color:blue;'>column 3</div>
    </td>
    <td id="columntarget">
      <div style='background-color:yellow;'>column 2</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick='HideColumn()'>Hide
</button>
```

Comment: That's it, however, `step-end` doesn't seem to work (while `ease` does)?

Comment: Note - I'm using Chrome. Update - also in FF.

Comment: @Vucko: As per [MDN for step-end](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function) - *Using this timing function, the animation stays in its initial state until the end, where it directly jumps to its final position.* So, it is working as expected (stays at full width for 2s and then jumps to 0 width) :)

Comment: As per that, it works. As the OP wants to animate it, can it be done (to animate `step-end`)?

Comment: @Vucko: No, OP wants only the delay not a gradual animation. I had asked this in comments and OP clarified. So, `step-end` is enough. With `display`, it doesn't even wait for the delay and with `visibility` or `opacity` it doesn't go 0 width.

Comment: Sorry, my bed :) didn't see the comment - just the title. GJ then :)

Comment: @Vucko No worries mate. It happens to all of us. I did it a couple of times myself yesterday :D

Comment: We have upvoted your answer, but edited the question, please take a look

Comment: @Wintermute: Sorry I didn't understand what the problem is with table width. It still hides after a delay. Are you referring to the small space at the end (the 3rd column)?

Comment: @Harry yes the problem is the white space

Comment: @Wintermute: Does the second snippet in my answer work for you? (*Note:* The table's width wouldn't decrease because its width has been set at 500px).

Answer (score 2):

try with this below code it may help you

```js
$("#hideBtn").click(function(){
  $("#columntarget").addClass("hideColumn");
});
```

```css
#columntarget{
  background: yellow;
}

td {
  width: 50px;
}

.hideColumn{
    max-width:50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: yellow;
   -moz-animation: hide 1s ease 3.5s forwards;
   -webkit-animation: slide 1s ease 3.5s forwards;
   -o-animation: slide 1s ease 3.5s forwards;
   -ms-animation: slide 1s ease 3.5s forwards;
    animation: slide 1s ease 3.5s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide /* Safari and Chrome */
{
from {max-width: 50px;}
to {max-width: 0px;}
}

@-moz-keyframes slide /* Safari and Chrome */
{
from {max-width: 50px;}
to {max-width: 0px;}
}
@keyframes slide
{
from {max-width: 50px;}
to {max-width: 0px;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style='background-color:red;'>column 1</td>
    <td id="columntarget">column 2</td>
    <td style='background-color:blue;'>column 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="hideBtn">Hide
  </button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi seems there is an easier way than the @Harry answer.
It's enought to add `table-layout: fixed;` and set `width:0`. No need to wrap all `<td>` contents in `<div>`s.

```js
function HideColumn() {
  var el = document.getElementById('columntarget');
  el.className += 'hideColumn';
}
```

```css
td {
  width: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.hideColumn {
  width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 2s step-end;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:500px;" border=1>
  <tr>
    <td style='background-color:red;'>
      column 1
    </td>
    <td style='background-color:blue; width:auto'>
      column 3
    </td>
    <td id="columntarget" style='background-color:yellow;'>
      column 2
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick='HideColumn()'>Hide
</button>
```

Comment: But with this approach the second `td` expands when the third is hidden.

Comment: You're right but it depends on what you expect to see. Sometimes could be a desired behaviour.